# Editing a published epub book

Tags: editing

I have tried for several hours to edit an eBook with Calibre, the page I wish to edit comes on screen but will not edit. I have read the instructions a dozen times and I cannot find an answer to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to tell us what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

Do you see this as in this [picture](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cs/_images/edit-book.png) when you're trying to edit an eBook?

You can only edit EPUB and AZW3 formats!

Here's the [tutorial](https://blog.cometdocs.com/how-to-edit-ebooks-in-epub-or-azw3-format-using-calibre) with pictures how to proceed when editing eBook in Calibre.

As an alternative, you can use [Sigil](https://sigil-ebook.com/) to create and/or edit EPUB format.